# Weird error message when tuning svm with polynomial kernel: "WARNING: reaching max number of iterations"

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

It is my first time working with support vector machines. I am trying to solve this homework, but am receiving the above mentioned error... The code is working for the linear kernel and radial kernel, but not for the polynomial kernel here is my code:

```
library(e1071)
test_data = #upload test data here.
training_data= read.table('Digits_training.csv', sep =',', header = TRUE)
y = training_data$y

chosen_svm = function(y,training_data,kernel_name){
  obj <- tune.svm(y~., data = training_data, gamma = 10^(-3:1), cost = 10^(-3:1), kernel = kernel_name)
  gamma = obj$best.parameters$gamma
  cost = obj$best.parameters$cost
  model = svm(y~., data = training_data, gamma = gamma, cost = cost,  kernel = kernel_name)
  return(model)
}

radial_svm = chosen_svm(y,training_data,'radial')
lin_svm = chosen_svm(y,training_data,'linear')
pol_svm = chosen_svm(y,training_data,'polynomial')
```

I tired to change the gamma and cost range a bit, and tried it with a second degree polynomial, but I am still getting the same error message.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This have been answered thoroughly on Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37669/libsvm-reaching-max-number-of-iterations-warning-and-cross-validation

Comment: As you can see, I already did what this thread says, and I am still getting the same error..

Comment: Can you tell anymore about your dataset? Is it balanced and normalised?

Comment: Yes the professor gave us a balanced and normalized dataset, since it is a beginners class. The dataset contains handwritten digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the error. It is just a warning, meaning that your optimizer did not converge in given number of iterations. Unfortunatley, the e1071 has internally a limit set... and you cannot change it

```
int max_iter = max(10000000, l>INT_MAX/100 ? INT_MAX : 100*l);
```

what you can do? Simply change the library, for example http://r.gmum.net  has the very same library (libsvm) available with this limitation dropped

https://github.com/gmum/gmum.r/blob/master/src/svm/svm.cpp (line 553)

```
[...]
int iter = 0;
// int max_iter = max(10000000, l>INT_MAX/100 ? INT_MAX : 100*l);
int counter = min(l,1000)+1;

while(1)
[...]
```

I am pretty sure that many others also dropped it. For example in python's scikit learn you can also explicitly state maximum number of iterations (and set -1 for lack of limit).