# Reduce the hyperparameter tuning running time (it takes unexpectedly too much time)

Tags: r, performance, xgboost, hyperparameters

I've a dataset with 6216 observations for 17 variables. I want to perform an `Extreme Gradient Boosting` and in order to improve the fitting I want to tune the hyperparameters. I'm using `train` function, where I give the grid with different hyperparameter values combination. The problem is that it takes about 1 hours to run the function and I don't understand why (my dataset is not so big to justify it). I posted about a similar problem with the `svm` hyperparameters tuning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402264/how-to-avoid-warning-reaching-max-number-of-iterations-while-using-tune-svm), where even by using just two parameter combinations It takes an hour. I'm quite new to R so maybe I'm missing something really basic, but after some research I didn't find anything.

I post the code so you can reproduce the situation, I hope someone will be able to because I don't really know how to do.

```
dput(x_scaled[1:200,])
structure(list(Season = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L), Region = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Age = c(23L, 29L, 25L, 22L, 22L, 27L, 24L, 24L, 29L, 28L, 
22L, 25L, 28L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 24L, 19L, 30L, 
21L, 22L, 32L, 22L, 34L, 29L, 22L, 30L, 23L, 30L, 23L, 30L, 30L, 
33L, 22L, 26L, 21L, 30L, 22L, 25L, 19L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 21L, 26L, 
23L, 26L, 31L, 31L, 33L, 20L, 23L, 29L, 25L, 28L, 21L, 23L, 28L, 
20L, 19L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 30L, 32L, 21L, 
34L, 19L, 29L, 20L, 25L, 20L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 21L, 26L, 24L, 33L, 
19L, 29L, 23L, 23L, 26L, 36L, 29L, 25L, 28L, 34L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 28L, 24L, 29L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 24L, 30L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 
24L, 23L, 20L, 24L, 36L, 32L, 20L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 24L, 27L, 27L, 
20L, 32L, 29L, 22L, 19L, 33L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 30L, 33L, 20L, 28L, 
31L, 25L, 30L, 27L, 24L, 25L, 21L, 32L, 27L, 28L, 23L, 30L, 26L, 
36L, 32L, 29L, 36L, 22L, 29L, 20L, 24L, 25L, 22L, 33L, 25L, 25L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 27L, 38L, 23L, 21L, 35L, 23L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
22L, 26L, 19L, 21L, 29L, 26L, 21L, 23L, 31L, 25L, 23L, 22L, 26L, 
25L, 27L, 22L, 20L, 25L, 21L, 27L, 22L), HtCm = c(203L, 211L, 
206L, 196L, 211L, 193L, 211L, 183L, 206L, 213L, 188L, 201L, 190L, 
206L, 211L, 208L, 211L, 206L, 201L, 208L, 196L, 206L, 203L, 206L, 
198L, 198L, 211L, 203L, 193L, 198L, 208L, 201L, 206L, 211L, 203L, 
198L, 201L, 198L, 196L, 201L, 206L, 196L, 208L, 196L, 201L, 198L, 
196L, 206L, 198L, 218L, 188L, 198L, 198L, 201L, 216L, 201L, 196L, 
203L, 208L, 206L, 208L, 193L, 183L, 198L, 196L, 203L, 193L, 211L, 
201L, 206L, 211L, 185L, 196L, 201L, 198L, 188L, 203L, 208L, 196L, 
193L, 190L, 213L, 190L, 198L, 211L, 206L, 196L, 208L, 208L, 196L, 
201L, 190L, 198L, 190L, 208L, 198L, 190L, 208L, 208L, 203L, 193L, 
203L, 198L, 213L, 206L, 201L, 185L, 203L, 188L, 193L, 201L, 190L, 
190L, 206L, 208L, 185L, 203L, 211L, 203L, 203L, 203L, 198L, 201L, 
216L, 190L, 203L, 185L, 193L, 203L, 193L, 196L, 198L, 206L, 196L, 
196L, 193L, 196L, 196L, 193L, 193L, 198L, 198L, 203L, 196L, 213L, 
203L, 196L, 201L, 206L, 211L, 196L, 193L, 201L, 193L, 190L, 208L, 
206L, 193L, 198L, 203L, 201L, 203L, 190L, 208L, 203L, 211L, 193L, 
208L, 211L, 203L, 206L, 193L, 206L, 201L, 196L, 196L, 198L, 211L, 
211L, 211L, 183L, 208L, 201L, 213L, 196L, 216L, 201L, 208L, 208L, 
201L, 216L, 196L, 201L, 218L, 203L, 203L, 198L, 203L, 196L, 198L
), WtKg = c(102L, 120L, 116L, 98L, 102L, 90L, 110L, 81L, 104L, 
110L, 84L, 105L, 88L, 95L, 113L, 127L, 107L, 100L, 82L, 113L, 
98L, 100L, 102L, 103L, 97L, 82L, 107L, 104L, 94L, 90L, 102L, 
98L, 106L, 113L, 116L, 100L, 103L, 91L, 93L, 84L, 91L, 86L, 112L, 
82L, 99L, 95L, 104L, 93L, 101L, 111L, 86L, 93L, 97L, 104L, 79L, 
87L, 93L, 107L, 109L, 122L, 122L, 84L, 78L, 86L, 98L, 98L, 88L, 
98L, 95L, 107L, 113L, 79L, 95L, 95L, 100L, 84L, 90L, 115L, 89L, 
91L, 88L, 111L, 91L, 100L, 95L, 103L, 92L, 114L, 98L, 98L, 104L, 
98L, 93L, 86L, 127L, 86L, 93L, 109L, 113L, 98L, 102L, 98L, 79L, 
127L, 109L, 100L, 79L, 95L, 93L, 95L, 93L, 84L, 95L, 93L, 106L, 
87L, 100L, 107L, 113L, 100L, 95L, 82L, 104L, 117L, 91L, 107L, 
88L, 81L, 103L, 93L, 91L, 101L, 113L, 93L, 84L, 79L, 93L, 100L, 
90L, 95L, 100L, 98L, 103L, 98L, 113L, 98L, 88L, 102L, 97L, 113L, 
88L, 100L, 100L, 85L, 93L, 107L, 109L, 106L, 100L, 93L, 86L, 
102L, 78L, 107L, 86L, 104L, 88L, 93L, 110L, 100L, 113L, 75L, 
100L, 109L, 100L, 84L, 110L, 129L, 111L, 99L, 89L, 95L, 98L, 
109L, 93L, 111L, 100L, 109L, 115L, 98L, 104L, 95L, 92L, 113L, 
88L, 95L, 103L, 107L, 91L, 81L), Exp = c(2L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 14L, 10L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 
5L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
9L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
8L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 15L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
9L, 8L, 13L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 10L, 1L, 
6L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 
4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 13L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 
0L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 14L, 13L, 7L, 
15L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 19L, 
2L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 0L), G = c(55L, 
42L, 75L, 59L, 77L, 72L, 68L, 61L, 69L, 63L, 60L, 67L, 20L, 76L, 
67L, 36L, 42L, 31L, 36L, 72L, 58L, 28L, 82L, 77L, 73L, 56L, 35L, 
78L, 50L, 52L, 45L, 77L, 20L, 38L, 61L, 54L, 59L, 14L, 53L, 22L, 
76L, 34L, 12L, 66L, 76L, 83L, 67L, 16L, 67L, 36L, 68L, 78L, 51L, 
64L, 19L, 18L, 76L, 60L, 65L, 11L, 57L, 67L, 36L, 41L, 64L, 56L, 
61L, 76L, 50L, 71L, 63L, 67L, 61L, 48L, 12L, 56L, 59L, 56L, 28L, 
64L, 12L, 38L, 32L, 74L, 22L, 22L, 56L, 31L, 39L, 79L, 66L, 74L, 
16L, 58L, 67L, 46L, 22L, 47L, 67L, 82L, 79L, 36L, 16L, 66L, 39L, 
66L, 53L, 52L, 25L, 23L, 27L, 73L, 60L, 68L, 78L, 69L, 75L, 28L, 
56L, 56L, 76L, 68L, 59L, 70L, 62L, 68L, 73L, 76L, 57L, 32L, 60L, 
72L, 41L, 71L, 56L, 47L, 71L, 58L, 48L, 48L, 74L, 34L, 74L, 76L, 
82L, 80L, 76L, 50L, 42L, 38L, 67L, 80L, 54L, 46L, 67L, 42L, 63L, 
65L, 56L, 51L, 75L, 67L, 56L, 16L, 45L, 11L, 74L, 63L, 63L, 23L, 
55L, 73L, 70L, 18L, 63L, 40L, 30L, 69L, 41L, 46L, 80L, 15L, 18L, 
36L, 59L, 74L, 74L, 37L, 38L, 63L, 58L, 72L, 37L, 69L, 29L, 67L, 
62L, 35L, 77L, 15L), MP = c(20.7, 27, 34.6, 20.5, 21.8, 27.4, 
32.6, 21.5, 28.4, 32.1, 25.9, 35.6, 8.6, 26.6, 30.4, 10, 23.6, 
7.3, 35.2, 33.8, 31.7, 14.6, 32.5, 34.8, 33.9, 17.7, 14.5, 21.9, 
33.5, 13.5, 10.9, 27.6, 8.1, 12, 14.3, 27.9, 32.1, 4.9, 34.6, 
11.3, 20, 15.1, 2.8, 23.5, 15.5, 35.7, 26, 5.8, 35.9, 8.2, 35, 
30.3, 22, 33.4, 11.6, 13.3, 31.3, 14.8, 26.6, 2.5, 29.6, 23.5, 
7.8, 12.5, 12.3, 19.5, 32.6, 29.9, 12.5, 30, 22.9, 30.3, 23.7, 
16.2, 33.3, 34.7, 17.7, 34, 15.1, 13.1, 5.5, 11.2, 6.7, 36.2, 
8.9, 8, 17.8, 11.5, 14.6, 34.5, 36.2, 30.7, 4.9, 15, 12.7, 19.5, 
25.8, 35.6, 24.9, 21.5, 36, 10.7, 4.4, 34.6, 10.4, 30.4, 13, 
14.7, 10.7, 12, 17, 33.4, 29.6, 15.1, 20.6, 35.5, 12.9, 8.7, 
14.6, 34.6, 31.1, 35.5, 10.6, 30.7, 17.8, 30.2, 18.3, 34.2, 14, 
15, 25.7, 19.5, 13.9, 29.9, 33.6, 16, 30.3, 36.8, 14.8, 24.7, 
20.6, 13.4, 32.9, 32.3, 19.8, 16.1, 28.3, 31.5, 14.6, 12.1, 34.9, 
31, 17.9, 18.1, 32.6, 8.3, 30.5, 20.2, 14.4, 15.9, 29.4, 31.7, 
19.4, 11.6, 34.2, 11.3, 31.1, 16.5, 28.4, 4.7, 35.5, 19.1, 14.9, 
9, 32.7, 10.4, 15.6, 33.7, 11.6, 12, 24.3, 13.6, 12.9, 6.5, 22.3, 
23, 28.3, 25.1, 7.7, 15.1, 13.8, 20.8, 9.5, 11.7, 5.7, 20.8, 
19.3, 11.8, 35.9, 7.2), FGA = c(7.3, 6.3, 14.9, 6.5, 6.8, 7.7, 
9.2, 8, 7.2, 20.3, 10.2, 13.2, 1.9, 7.6, 13.2, 2, 9.1, 3.5, 20, 
15.6, 16.2, 3.1, 9.6, 13.2, 16.1, 6.5, 3.9, 4.9, 17.6, 4.7, 3.6, 
10.9, 1.6, 3.3, 3.4, 11.3, 14.9, 1.4, 20.1, 5.5, 7, 5.7, 1, 9.3, 
3.8, 15.3, 10.9, 1.8, 20.6, 2.7, 17.6, 6, 9, 13.9, 2.8, 3.7, 
8.3, 3.8, 8.2, 0.7, 10.8, 4.3, 2.3, 2.6, 5.1, 6.2, 16.9, 7.7, 
2.9, 10, 8.7, 9.1, 6.9, 4.8, 18.7, 20.2, 3.5, 17.2, 6.1, 5.7, 
1.6, 4, 1.6, 17.6, 2.1, 2.3, 6.7, 3.8, 4.6, 13.3, 22, 11.8, 2.1, 
5.8, 4.1, 7.2, 9.8, 18.3, 5.9, 8, 19.5, 2.6, 1, 20.1, 2.9, 7.6, 
4.6, 6, 3.3, 2.6, 6.1, 18.2, 11.3, 3.8, 5.1, 16.4, 2.4, 4.1, 
5.1, 17.9, 14.7, 20.3, 2.2, 7.8, 5.7, 11.2, 5.9, 17.9, 4.4, 3.4, 
6.4, 7.4, 3.2, 8.5, 15, 5, 11.9, 14.5, 6.9, 6.4, 5.9, 3.1, 11.4, 
6.8, 4, 5, 10.7, 11.6, 2.7, 4.4, 16.6, 13, 4, 3.6, 15.3, 2.1, 
7.6, 9.4, 3.5, 3.6, 11.5, 12.3, 10.2, 3.4, 18.6, 4.8, 13.3, 5, 
13, 1.2, 22.2, 7, 4.6, 2.7, 17.7, 4.5, 4.1, 14.8, 2.1, 2.6, 8.9, 
4.6, 5.8, 1.8, 6.5, 5.6, 7.9, 4.6, 2.1, 5.3, 2.6, 4.4, 3, 2.5, 
1.3, 7.4, 5.1, 2.7, 18, 2.9), FT = c(1.6, 1.1, 4.3, 0.9, 1.4, 
1.6, 2.4, 1.1, 1.4, 7.9, 2.5, 2.1, 0, 1.6, 2.3, 0.2, 1.9, 0.1, 
2.8, 5.5, 3.1, 0.6, 4.3, 2.5, 4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 3.8, 0.5, 0.3, 
2.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 1.2, 4.5, 0, 5.8, 1.3, 1.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.9, 
0.5, 3.8, 2.4, 0.3, 3.9, 0.9, 4.8, 0.3, 3, 7.4, 0.2, 0.9, 1.4, 
0.6, 1.2, 0.2, 2.5, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 1.8, 3.3, 1.8, 1, 2, 
1.7, 2.1, 0.4, 0.6, 3, 4.6, 0.4, 6.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 
6.2, 0.5, 0.1, 1.6, 0.3, 0.4, 3.4, 7.8, 2.7, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.3, 
1.9, 6.5, 1.4, 1.3, 4, 0.3, 0.3, 10, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 
0.1, 0.7, 4.7, 1.9, 0.8, 1.6, 4, 0.4, 1.5, 0.8, 4.6, 1.4, 9.8, 
0.8, 3.1, 0.9, 2.8, 1.3, 4.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1.1, 0.6, 0.5, 1.1, 3.1, 
1.2, 1.8, 5.4, 1.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7, 0.6, 0.2, 1.2, 2.6, 
0.2, 2.1, 2.5, 1.3, 0.2, 0.9, 2.3, 0.4, 0.2, 1.9, 0.8, 0.3, 1.3, 
2.6, 1.5, 0.5, 5.3, 0.5, 3.6, 1.5, 3.8, 0, 4.6, 1.1, 0.7, 0.2, 
3.9, 0.7, 0.9, 4.9, 0.5, 0.4, 1, 1.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 1.1, 1, 
0.7, 1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0, 1.3, 0.7, 0.2, 4.7, 0.1), 
    FTA = c(2.3, 3.1, 5.4, 1.2, 1.9, 1.8, 3.3, 1.3, 2, 12.3, 
    2.8, 2.5, 0, 2.2, 3, 0.6, 2.6, 0.2, 3.4, 7.4, 3.5, 0.9, 5, 
    3.2, 5.4, 0.8, 1.1, 0.6, 4.6, 0.7, 0.3, 3.1, 0.3, 1.1, 1.1, 
    1.4, 5.1, 0, 6.8, 1.7, 2.2, 0.9, 0.3, 1.1, 0.8, 4.3, 2.7, 
    0.8, 5.1, 2, 5.8, 0.5, 3.7, 8.7, 0.2, 1.2, 1.6, 0.7, 2, 0.2, 
    3.4, 1.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9, 2.4, 4, 3.2, 1.3, 2.5, 2.3, 2.5, 
    0.7, 0.8, 3.6, 5, 0.7, 7.9, 1, 0.7, 0.2, 1.3, 0.2, 7.1, 0.7, 
    0.1, 2.6, 0.4, 0.6, 4.2, 10.5, 3.5, 0, 0.8, 1.9, 1.6, 2.4, 
    7.1, 2.3, 1.8, 5.3, 0.4, 0.4, 11.7, 1.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.1, 0.8, 6, 2.4, 1.2, 2.4, 4.7, 0.6, 1.9, 0.9, 5.3, 1.9, 
    10.9, 1.1, 4.9, 1.1, 4.6, 1.8, 6.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 0.7, 0.8, 
    1.4, 3.6, 1.6, 2.3, 6.2, 1.6, 0.6, 0.4, 1.2, 1.7, 2.3, 0.9, 
    0.2, 1.5, 3.2, 0.4, 2.7, 2.7, 1.6, 0.5, 1.2, 2.6, 0.5, 0.3, 
    2.6, 1.1, 0.4, 1.7, 3.1, 1.8, 0.8, 6, 0.8, 4.8, 2.3, 4.9, 
    0.1, 5.9, 1.4, 1.1, 0.4, 5.2, 1, 1.3, 6, 0.7, 0.6, 1.3, 1.3, 
    0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 2.1, 1.2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.1, 
    2.1, 1, 0.3, 5.6, 0.5), TRB = c(6, 11.5, 9.2, 2.1, 4.8, 3.3, 
    9.8, 2.3, 5.3, 11.8, 4.8, 5, 0.8, 6.4, 10, 3.3, 6.4, 1.3, 
    6.4, 6.9, 5, 3.6, 4.5, 6.6, 5, 2.4, 5.5, 3.8, 3.9, 2.2, 1.2, 
    4.7, 1.3, 3.6, 4.3, 3.1, 3.8, 0.5, 4.5, 1.4, 5.5, 2.1, 0.9, 
    2.7, 2.4, 4.4, 4.2, 1.2, 6.9, 3.9, 3.5, 3.6, 3.1, 5.9, 0.9, 
    2.9, 2.7, 2.1, 11, 1, 8.7, 2.9, 1.1, 1.8, 1.1, 5.5, 4, 9.2, 
    1.1, 6.5, 6.4, 2.7, 4.6, 3.5, 6.2, 6.1, 3.2, 12.5, 2.3, 2.2, 
    0.8, 3.5, 0.4, 4.6, 2.3, 1.4, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 3.4, 8.6, 4.6, 
    0.9, 1.4, 6.6, 2.5, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 6, 5.8, 1.7, 0.5, 10.2, 
    3.5, 4.8, 1.4, 1.7, 0.6, 1.6, 1.8, 4.2, 3.9, 4.2, 5.6, 2.7, 
    4.1, 2.3, 2.9, 6.1, 7.9, 4.8, 1.7, 11.6, 3.3, 6.6, 1.7, 3.7, 
    3.6, 2.8, 3, 2.1, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 1.9, 3.5, 6.1, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 
    2.1, 5.7, 7.8, 6.5, 2.6, 2.9, 4.3, 2.9, 4.7, 5.4, 5, 3.5, 
    1.8, 5.1, 1.9, 6.2, 3.2, 1.7, 1.9, 3.3, 4.2, 2.4, 2.8, 5.5, 
    4, 3.9, 4.5, 6.8, 0.7, 8.3, 2.4, 4, 1.7, 5, 1.1, 3.2, 11.8, 
    3, 2.7, 2.5, 2.1, 2.2, 1.4, 2.7, 8.4, 2.8, 3.6, 1.5, 2.8, 
    2.9, 4.3, 1.1, 2.9, 0.9, 3.4, 3.5, 1.8, 4.5, 1.4), AST = c(0.9, 
    2.3, 3.2, 1.1, 1.3, 2.3, 1.7, 3, 4.9, 5.7, 3.9, 2, 1.2, 2.8, 
    1.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 8.4, 3.7, 4.4, 0.9, 1.6, 4.8, 2.8, 2, 
    1.3, 1.6, 5.4, 0.7, 0.5, 1.5, 0.4, 1, 0.9, 2.8, 2.6, 0.5, 
    5.5, 0.9, 0.4, 1.2, 0.1, 1.9, 0.8, 3.3, 3.7, 0.2, 3.5, 0.1, 
    6.2, 1.4, 2.2, 5.3, 0.6, 0.7, 2.4, 1.3, 0.9, 0.3, 2.3, 2.9, 
    1.6, 0.5, 1.1, 1.3, 4.4, 1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.9, 6.7, 1.3, 1.2, 
    6, 6.3, 2.3, 2.6, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.7, 1.3, 5.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 
    1.7, 1.2, 6.5, 8, 2.1, 0.6, 2.6, 0.5, 1.4, 5.6, 5, 1.1, 1.1, 
    4.4, 0.6, 0.4, 4.2, 0.8, 1.5, 1.3, 0.8, 0.7, 1.7, 1.3, 6.1, 
    5.7, 0.5, 1.1, 7.8, 0.9, 0.6, 1, 5.1, 6.2, 5.5, 0.6, 1.2, 
    2.7, 3, 2.7, 3.7, 0.9, 0.7, 1.7, 1, 1.5, 2.1, 10.4, 1.1, 
    1.8, 10.7, 1.4, 1.2, 1.4, 0.5, 2.5, 3.8, 1.2, 0.9, 6.2, 4.1, 
    0.6, 0.9, 4.2, 2.8, 0.8, 2.4, 7.4, 0.2, 3, 3.8, 0.8, 0.6, 
    2.9, 1.4, 3.1, 0.3, 5.8, 0.5, 5.2, 0.8, 1, 0.4, 6.8, 1.2, 
    1.2, 0.8, 2.9, 1.5, 2.2, 9.8, 0.4, 0.3, 5.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.9, 
    1.5, 0.9, 1.2, 1.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 1.9, 
    1.5, 0.6, 4.2, 0.1), BLK = c(0.5, 1.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 
    1.2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 
    0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 1.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.8, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 
    0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 1.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 
    0.2, 2.5, 0.1, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 2, 0.3, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 
    0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 1.4, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 
    1.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.3, 
    0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 1, 0.2, 1.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 
    0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 1.5, 3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 2.3, 0.1, 
    0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0
    ), TOV = c(1.1, 1.9, 2.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 3.9, 
    1.5, 2, 0.4, 1.6, 1.8, 0.5, 1.1, 0.4, 3.6, 2.8, 2.2, 0.5, 
    1, 2, 2.2, 0.9, 1.2, 0.6, 2.9, 0.9, 0.2, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 
    1.2, 2.3, 0.5, 2.7, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 1.2, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
    0.4, 2.9, 0.4, 2.1, 0.5, 1.1, 1.6, 0.1, 0.3, 1.1, 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.2, 1.9, 1.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 1, 3, 1.3, 0.4, 1.1, 2, 1.5, 
    0.5, 0.7, 3.3, 3.2, 1, 2.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 2.1, 
    0.4, 0.5, 1.3, 1, 0.7, 1.8, 3.6, 1.2, 0.3, 1.1, 1.1, 0.9, 
    1.6, 3.3, 1.4, 1.2, 3.3, 0.4, 0.1, 3.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 
    0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 2.5, 2.3, 0.7, 1.1, 2.9, 0.6, 0.5, 0.7, 3.1, 
    2.8, 2.8, 0.3, 1.7, 0.9, 1.4, 0.7, 2.6, 0.9, 0.6, 1.2, 0.6, 
    0.5, 1, 2.5, 0.9, 0.8, 3.4, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.2, 1.5, 0.8, 
    0.4, 2.3, 2, 0.4, 1, 2.4, 1.7, 0.8, 0.7, 2.9, 0.3, 0.6, 1.9, 
    0.5, 0.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 3.3, 0.4, 3.2, 0.8, 1.7, 0.1, 
    3.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 2.1, 1.1, 1.1, 3.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 0.7, 
    0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.2, 1.4, 0.9, 0.5, 2.5, 0.2), PTS = c(9.2, 8.6, 20.4, 7.9, 
    9, 10.4, 14.3, 9, 9.4, 31.1, 13, 16.8, 1.3, 9.2, 18, 3.5, 
    12, 3.9, 23.3, 20, 21.5, 3.9, 15, 15.3, 19.6, 6.8, 5.7, 6.1, 
    23.2, 5.1, 4.6, 13.8, 2.2, 4.4, 4.3, 14, 21.6, 0.4, 27.8, 
    6.5, 9.4, 5.6, 1.6, 10.2, 4.7, 20.1, 14.9, 1.8, 26.6, 4.3, 
    24, 7.2, 12.8, 22.9, 2.4, 5.4, 10.8, 5, 12, 0.5, 15.2, 5.6, 
    2.2, 3.1, 5.8, 10, 20.8, 12.6, 3.4, 13.1, 11.6, 11.9, 7.6, 
    6, 19.9, 29.4, 3.8, 25.9, 5.8, 6.7, 1.6, 5.2, 1.5, 24.5, 
    2.7, 2.6, 9.3, 3.9, 4.9, 17.3, 32.4, 13.7, 1.4, 6.3, 6, 7.9, 
    13.2, 29.1, 9.1, 9.3, 24.6, 2.8, 1.5, 33.1, 3.9, 8.3, 4.6, 
    6.3, 3.6, 2.3, 6.1, 25, 14, 5.5, 9, 21.6, 3, 6.5, 5.2, 23.8, 
    16.6, 31.4, 3.3, 13.4, 6.6, 16.3, 7.4, 22.1, 6.4, 5.2, 9.1, 
    8.9, 4.1, 11.3, 20.7, 6.4, 14.4, 21, 8.8, 8.3, 7.6, 4.1, 
    14.7, 9.8, 5, 6.4, 10.3, 14.7, 2.9, 6.9, 20.1, 16.8, 4.4, 
    5, 19.3, 3.1, 9.8, 10.7, 4.8, 3.8, 15.2, 15.4, 11.8, 4.1, 
    24.7, 5, 16.3, 7.2, 18.6, 0.9, 28.9, 9.5, 5.6, 2.8, 22, 4.7, 
    5.8, 24.5, 3.5, 3.4, 10.3, 5.5, 4.8, 2.5, 9.3, 9.2, 11.1, 
    5.9, 3.7, 6.6, 3.1, 5.1, 3.8, 3.8, 1.2, 9.9, 6.7, 3, 24.8, 
    3.7), sal_perc = c(0.0229684202013667, 0.144974558246735, 
    0.245455339452509, 0.031687841171, 0.0169351825643929, 0.0721766204358902, 
    0.161740325906757, 0.012644195544054, 0.0710079495370183, 
    0.343637475233513, 0.0292238890461364, 0.140367498281509, 
    0.0148484897497068, 0.0397570660304881, 0.25, 0.0175882900004043, 
    0.101087703691723, 0.018001698273422, 0.0697417815696899, 
    0.0894029355869152, 0.0172272855929805, 0.00411540980955077, 
    0.148415130807489, 0.0618220047713396, 0.0881536047875136, 
    0.121788136347095, 0.0216306821398245, 0.159316800776354, 
    0.35, 0.0200978528971736, 0.129392260725405, 0.0239301281792083, 
    0.053920181149165, 0.0434880918685051, 0.0234996643888237, 
    0.145566293316081, 0.158101168573855, 0.013823136953621, 
    0.273611257126683, 0.012644195544054, 0.102624236787837, 
    0.0352775059641745, 0.0164677368484898, 0.0236593748736404, 
    0.0227131939670858, 0.16254902753629, 0.182766568274635, 
    0.012644195544054, 0.232429509522462, 0.00666403299502649, 
    0.224279907808014, 0.0809736767619587, 0.0809736767619587, 
    0.304502850673244, 0.00406810076422304, 0.00411540980955077, 
    0.113256261372367, 0.0180692976426347, 0.147239464639521, 
    0.0152247867049452, 0.11443128057903, 0.0730257571469007, 
    0.0097044195544054, 0.00823081153208524, 0.0191836965751486, 
    0.0351293437386276, 0.107880797379807, 0.0756136023614088, 
    0.0274559217176823, 0.190044882940439, 0.0594395697707331, 
    0.183413529578262, 0.0463256075370992, 0.0995325057619991, 
    0.0853406655614411, 0.388742986535118, 0.044548137964498, 
    0.307150701548664, 0.0389011362257895, 0.0323480651813513, 
    0.00411540980955077, 0.0669903198414945, 0.0212575067728761, 
    0.220775544862723, 0.00411540980955077, 0.00411540980955077, 
    0.0420524847357567, 0.0331991104282075, 0.0369563705470866, 
    0.157696817759088, 0.3, 0.123551639642554, 0.00634550968420201, 
    0.0284967207148922, 0.0258784521450811, 0.0318382596740932, 
    0.00808702438235413, 0.35679790546278, 0.0333531195665359, 
    0.027165581658647, 0.0868011807043791, 0.0132462577332093, 
    0.00411540980955077, 0.271859366786624, 0.0219755852978044, 
    0.104644761635195, 0.0173524726052323, 0.0259199223646436, 
    0.0185870769479601, 0.00411540980955077, 0.145566293316081, 
    0.245455339452509, 0.133435768873074, 0.0151932392543771, 
    0.0156134487080991, 0.072142606445352, 0.019984311188387, 
    0.00411540980955077, 0.0500141522785168, 0.343637475233513, 
    0.0508463062553071, 0.25, 0.0148484897497068, 0.308700934050382, 
    0.0103530467833893, 0.159240701953014, 0.093405038211152, 
    0.0763563139379726, 0.0663135336217703, 0.0146834094860701, 
    0.0250568112894747, 0.0285969835429218, 0.0234996643888237, 
    0.0184141361044843, 0.0340877441268044, 0.0234381383688488, 
    0.158523901176661, 0.266871537746149, 0.00823081153208524, 
    0.105131211839392, 0.150765088350653, 0.00411540980955077, 
    0.304339088593264, 0.104807731187578, 0.0716095507662448, 
    0.0132462577332093, 0.0472100602482714, 0.243217015082285, 
    0.0185870769479601, 0.0197612793659779, 0.0462748453358134, 
    0.171264809348591, 0.0141736120658283, 0.0323480651813513, 
    0.2722497270632, 0.0906979903764506, 0.214305931826453, 0.0829727871901662, 
    0.0331972018923618, 0.0161740325906757, 0.1173339452509, 
    0.0795429299260038, 0.0178037281145122, 0.0234996643888237, 
    0.25595891795722, 0.140714083538878, 0.058648659577049, 0.0208140390602887, 
    0.234091666329708, 0.0148484897497068, 0.359669952690955, 
    0.0148484897497068, 0.0225841251870123, 0.0310627714204844, 
    0.0313212082002345, 0.0216816141684525, 0.0325273058105212, 
    0.267258121386115, 0.0185870769479601, 0.0235254538837896, 
    0.121305244430068, 0.0181142695402531, 0.00411540980955077, 
    0.0199222837734018, 0.111159718571833, 0.0218058307387489, 
    0.0287318749747281, 0.0727831466580405, 0.0148484897497068, 
    0.0242610488860135, 0.0121305244430068, 0.018600137479277, 
    0.0404350814766892, 0.0172518539484857, 0.012644195544054, 
    0.0464181796126319, 0.00561948970927176, 0.0246463143423234, 
    0.3, 0.00300377663660992)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 
38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 111L, 112L, 
115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
127L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 153L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 167L, 168L, 
169L, 170L, 171L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 181L, 
182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 190L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 
195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 202L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 210L, 212L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 223L, 
225L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 
238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 244L, 247L, 248L, 249L), class = "data.frame")
```

I posted only the first 200 rows in order to keep the question not so long, if you bind the dataset 31 times it will have same dimensions as mine.

```
x_scaled[,names(x_scaled)!="sal_perc"] <- scale(x_scaled[,names(x_scaled)!="sal_perc"])
set.seed(123)
xgb.control_game <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5,returnResamp="all")
xgb.tunegrid_game <- expand.grid(nrounds=1000,
                                 max_depth=c(4,6,8,10),
                                 eta=c(0.1,0.01,0.001),
                                 gamma=0,
                                 colsample_bytree=c(0.6,0.8,1),
                                 min_child_weight=1,
                                 subsample=c(0.75,1)
)
tune.xgb_game <- train(sal_perc ~., data=x_scaled, method="xgbTree", metric="RMSE", 
                       tuneGrid=xgb.tunegrid_game, trControl=xgb.control_game)
```

If I reduce the `nrounds` hyperparameter tuning is clearly faster, but I wouldn't like building a worse model just because it will takes longer to create a better model, which normally should be fast. (I've even limited the 10-fold cv to a 5-fold)

Comment: How long does it take to run a single iteration (say with depth=10). Your grid has 4x3x3x2 combinations, and you're doing 5 fold cv per combination so you're building a lot of models. In general random search will outperform a grid search for the same computational cost (and can often find a better solution since it's not constrained to grid points) and algorithms like `optuna` can do better still.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth If I remove the cv and set `max_depth=10`, `eta=0.01`,`colsample=0.8` and `subsample=0.75` it takes about 9 minutes, I think it's too much

Comment: Thank you for the optuna solution by the way

Comment: You may also want to consider less iterations (nrounds) with a higher learning rate (you're not tuning this afaict) and potentially (assuming it's supported) early stopping.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth Thanks a lot. I reduced the nrounds yesterday and I noticed it was the hyperparameter more relevant in the running time. And the performances didn't change so much with the lower value of nrounds

Comment: I would expect it to be fairly linear? If its what I think it is (the number of iterations) then halving it should more or less half runtime